# Ideolog не рисует heatmap для моего формата лога

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea, pycharm, логирование

Настроил новый формат лога в плагине *Ideolog*, содержащий только строки с *severity* INFO и ERROR, отличающиеся наличием цифры/нецифры в определённом месте сообщения. В итоге сами строки подсвечиваются верно и почти все функции работают кроме *heat map* на скроллбаре справа, а это самое полезное, как по мне. Как можно пофиксить это? На формате *IntelliJ IDEA* есть подсветка справа. Галка *Show on stripe* стоит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Для полного функционирования плагина *Ideolog* формат лог-файла должен соответствовать одному из шаблонов из таблицы **Log Formats**. [Алгоритм сопоставления](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideolog/wiki/Custom-Log-Formats#log-format-detection) следующий:

> ... все существующие шаблоны сопоставляются с первыми 25 строками файла. Выбирается тот, у которого больше всего совпадений, если количество совпадений больше 5. В противном случае используется тупой построчный синтаксический анализатор.

Судя по всему у вас *противный* случай (в верху окна появляется сообщение **Log format not recognized**, если только вы не отключили его насовсем)

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что heatmap рисуется не по Patterns, а по захваченной Severity группе. Так что если у вас INFO и ERROR отличаются только паттернами, то это работать не будет.